# Run Bluetooth application on Virtual Device Simulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth

I just finished a spiffy new Bluetooth application and am ready to put it on the market.  Generally what I do is run the application on the simulator and use snagit to get some screen shots.  Problem is the application force closes on the emulator.  I think this is because of the Bluetooth Calls I am making in the application.  Since it is a virtual device running on a windows 7 based computer I don't believe it has access to the computer's built in Bluethooth.  Anyone know of a way around this or a way to tie the virtual device to the computers Bluetooth adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you tested this with a real device?

You can always use the DDMS to take screen shots from an actual device.

Comment: Yes, it has been tested on several Android phones as well as tablet running multiple versions of the Android OS.  I'm not familiar with DDMS though, can you explain or show a link?

Comment: it is in the directory you installed the SDK /android-sdk/tools/ there is a batch file called DDMS that will start the debugger window, from there you can select from the android devices that are active, then press crtl-s or select screen capture from device menu http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html